# Docker swarm: One container per connection?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm

How would you implement a system that allocates one docker container per connection?

For example, the service receives a connection on port $x. I would like to route that connection to a single container in my swarm, and that container will handle data from only that connection/client. When the client disconnects the container can be destroyed. I need at least as many containers in the swarm as connections, but ideally not many more (e.g. a few percent extra in case of failures).

Does docker swarm allow for this sort of control over load balancing? (Caveat: I'm new to Docker).

Comment: This sounds more like a serverless architecture. eg AWS lambda

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with Docker without an add-ons and I have not heard of one. Knative supports this on Kubernetes. Google implemented this in the Google Cloud Run service.

Comment: I just noticed the Fn Project tonight that runs on Docker. I have no experience with Fn. https://fnproject.io/